# Table with 1-30 match data from database

Tags: sql-server

I've been creating this table manually and hoping I can automate it.
What i have in excel is a table with with days of the Month example June 1-30 what I need to do is populate the data based on sales and a separate based on accumulative ... example

Data

```
1 - $100
2 - $300
5 - $300
```

What i need to see is :

```
1 - $100
2 - $400
3 - $400
4 - $400
5 - $700
```

What my issue is the days that have 0 / no sales does not populate into the database

here is the code I have to get the data :

```
IF DAY (GETDATE()) = 1
SELECT Office,NetNet_Revenue_USD,NetNet_GM_USD,[DayOfMonth],[Month],[Year]
FROM Datawarehouse.dbo.Sales_History Sales_History
WHERE (Sales_History.Cust_Intercompany <> 'Yes - VAP') AND Year = (YEAR(GETDATE())) and [Period] = MONTH(GETDATE()-1)

else IF DAY (GETDATE()) <> 1
SELECT Office,NetNet_Revenue_USD,NetNet_GM_USD,[DayOfMonth],[Month],[Year]
FROM Datawarehouse.dbo.Sales_History Sales_History
WHERE (Sales_History.Cust_Intercompany <> 'Yes - VAP') AND Year = (YEAR(GETDATE())) and [Period] = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Any help would be apricated as I'm over doing it manually :(

---

New code using the idea of joining my data to a table that has every day of the month

```
SELECT distinct CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(AUDTDATE AS VARCHAR(8)), 112) as StringToDate 
,Office,(NetNet_Revenue_USD),[DayOfMonth],[Month],[Year],InvoiceNumber,Revenue_Func
FROM [ACCPACAU].[dbo].[CSCRD]
left join Datawarehouse.dbo.Sales_History on Sales_History.TranDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(AUDTDATE AS VARCHAR(8)), 112)
where year(CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(AUDTDATE AS VARCHAR(8)), 112)) = (YEAR(GETDATE()))
and
Month(CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(AUDTDATE AS VARCHAR(8)), 112)) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Comment: do you have access to a date table? My thinking is.. if you do.. then you simply get all the dates in the table for the month, join to your data.. and then run a sum(over) statement to get a cumulative total.

Comment: hey Harry i tired this but have a different issue now :(

I used the following but where i want it show 0 it doesnt have the office etc it has the date which is a plus but all the other values are blank

(i added an updated code in the main)

Comment: If your base table is the table where data does not exist, then it won't be part of your output.. obviously. Base the from statement from dim_date for example..  and where the data is null, wrap an isnull to get a 0 value for that date.. meaning 0 sales for that date

Comment: so used the date table as the master and linked in my sales to those date and it is giving me a "NULL" but where im having the drama is there can more the one office is it possible to have the null for each off or can this not be achieved ?
so if there are no sales on 12/06/2021 id like to see Office 1 = 0 Office 2 = 0 atm its just got the date and null for all other fields

Comment: what you are looking for is to pad out data .. so you will need to cross join to office to get all office location and when you get a cross over, you can aggregate to get rid of duplicates.. Hope that makes sense..

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to run a union statement to get all the office location you want, aggregate the data and then do a sum over to get a running total.  I have come up with a simplified version of the same.. hope this helps you achieve what you want.

I've kept it pretty simple to show what you could do

```
    if object_id('tempdb..#office') is not null 
drop table #office

if object_id('tempdb..#data') is not null 
drop table #data

;with offices as (
select 1 as office
union all
select 2 as office
union all
select 3 as office
union all
select 4 as office
union all
select 5 as office

)

Select * into #office 
from offices

;with sales as (
select 1 as office , 100 as sales
union all
select 2 as office , 300 as sales
union all
select 5 as office , 300 as sales
)

Select * into #data
from sales

; with all_data as (
select #data.* 
from #data

union 

select office,0 as sales
from #office

where office NOT IN (select office from #data)
)



Select 
    office
    , sales
    , sum(sales) over ( order by office) as runing_total 
from all_data

drop table #data
drop table #office
```